# Rails Routing Clash When Rendering Static Pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a routing clash. After moving all of my blog posts from `/posts/:id` to `/:id` (which is great), I now have an issue where my static pages don't contain an ID, so they aren't rendering. I don't want to have to process them through my posts controller.

Here's what I currently have in my routes.rb file:

```
  resources :posts, only: [:index, :create, :edit, :new, :destroy]
  get '/:id' => 'posts#show', :as => 'custom_url'
  match '/posts/:id' => redirect('/%{id}', status: 301)
```

But then these now don't work...

```
  match '/privacy' => 'static#privacy'
  match '/terms' => 'static#terms'
```

I have a controller called static_controller.rb which I can use if I need to. How can I jump over the `/:id` match.

***UPDATE:***

Also experiencing issues where my def update isn't updating my content.

```
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
        format.html { redirect_to @post, :notice => 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render :json => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: UPDATE:

Also experincing issues where my `def update` won't work with this code:

`
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
        format.html { redirect_to @post, :notice => 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render :json => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails matches routes from top to bottom order, so the higher to the top, the higher priority. See [Rails Routing from the Outside In](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). If you move these routes

```
  match '/privacy' => 'static#privacy'
  match '/terms' => 'static#terms'
```

above these routes, then the static routes will have priority over the blog posts and should render correctly.

```
  resources :posts, only: [:index, :create, :edit, :new, :destroy]
  get '/:id' => 'posts#show', :as => 'custom_url'
  match '/posts/:id' => redirect('/%{id}', status: 301)
```

Note, this means if you have any blog post ids that clash with static page routes, the static pages will match and be displayed.

Comment: `constraints: { id: /\d+/ }` on the `get '/:id'` is another option if the IDs are numeric and the static pages aren't.

Comment: Hey guys, using this code, I also have a problem where my edit functionality isn't updating the content. Any help there?

Comment: I've updated this post to include my code if you can help me out!

Comment: seems like update is not present in your routing : `resources :posts, only: [:index, :create, :edit, :new, :destroy]`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the scenario you are describing you should NOT match out and by-pass  `/posts/` with the redirect. That breaks rails pattern of hierarchy and order and will potentially make your code messier than it need to. @Chris Selemers answer is correct but as he points out there are potential (if very limited) risks with that approach.

```
get '/posts/:id' => 'posts#show', :as => 'custom_url'
```

Or better yet simply do:

```
resources :posts
```